# The Mirror Monitoring Log contains a gap of several hours - why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

I am running mirroring on several databases on a SQL Server 2008 R2 system (I know, don't judge me).

I ran this to look at the mirroring log

```
EXEC sp_dbmmonitorresults
    GANDALF, --database
    4,      -- last day
    0;      -- don't update status
```

And I noticed that there is a gap of several hours

```
time_recorded
--------------------------    
2021-03-04 10:15:39.930
2021-03-04 10:15:39.930
**
2021-03-04 10:15:09.913
**
2021-03-03 20:43:36.690
2021-03-03 20:43:36.690
2021-03-03 20:43:20.743
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to why this might happen?